# How can I add label inside a progress bar tag?

Tags: html, progress-bar

I want to add a label in my progress bar tag like in this beautiful example:

[image]

Assuming the blue is the value and the red is the max, how can I add a label inside there like my "35"?

Comment: Old question, but up-vote because that presentation was fabulous.

Comment: "beautiful example" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS's `position:relative` to manoeuvre the text onto the bar.

A quick and dirty solution for a short bar is:

```
position: relative;
left: -100px;
```

where left forces the text that would be next to the bar on top of it.

In the comments, Matthias made the point that `left` doesn't work if the progress bar is 100% width.

It doesn't work because it forces the text below the bar. It'll fail for any width of bar sufficient to force the text below.

Instead you have to get a bit more clever and do something like:

```
    position: relative;
    top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: 50%;
```

Here the top:-1.5em replaces the left adjustment in the jsFiddle. The margin-left is an attempt to centre the text. It should actually be a little less than 50%.

If someone has a better solution to centre the text on the bar that's less hacky than the hand-wavy 50%ish margin feel free to comment on it and I'll adjust this again.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Updated with a fix for that.

Answer (score 3):

I attempted to do this myself and finally came across a workaround.

Using the pseudo element :before you can do it a different way

You use *content: attr(value)* like this: https://jsfiddle.net/96z0gwv7/1/ - more CSS styling on link

```
progress
{
  text-align:center;
}

progress:before {
  content: 'Value is ' attr(value);
}

<progress value="6" max="10"></progress>
<progress value="9" max="10"></progress>
```

If you're not wanting the same text format each time then you could use the data attribute (i.e *data-label*)

```
.unique:before {
   content: attr(data-label);
}

<progress class="unique" value="9" max="10" data-label="90% completed"></progress>
<progress class="unique" value="0" max="10" data-label="About to begin"></progress>
```

Comment: Anyone know the solution to firefox ?