# HTML/Javascript Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I am currently working with a progress bar in javascript and I am trying to display the percent inside the progress bar.

I keep getting examples that do it with creating a div inside another div when searching but I was wondering if it is possible with an actual progress bar.  Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yjyrkLtm/1/

```
   <progress class="progress-1" id="health" value="3" max="5">test</progress>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add label inside a progress bar tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452594/how-can-i-add-label-inside-a-progress-bar-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value::before {
  content: '80%';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yjyrkLtm/4/